# Problem using module_load_include

Tags: 6, nodes

I need to use `node_add()`, but when I called it in my module I get the "undefined function" message.

So I'm trying to include it using `module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages')`, but I'm getting the error message:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/vhosts/****.es/httpdocs/includes/common.inc on line 2946

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe errors are below in your code. Try to comment your lines of code one by one and you will find which function called incorrect.

Comment: nop because if i comment the line with module_load_include it works although I get the message "undefined function"

Comment: But you could call `node_add()` in wrong way and got error when it was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you 3 method to  add a node programatically

- first method

  ```
  // required for Drupal 6
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
  // which nodeform you want
  $node_type = 'YOURNODETYPE';
  $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
  // maybe add current users info
  global $user;
  // create a blank node
  $node = array(
   'uid' => $user->uid,
   'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
   'type' => $node_type,
    );
    // Invoke hook_nodapi and hook_node
    node_object_prepare($node);
   // Or you can also use an exiting node, for example
   // $node = node_load(123);
   // and the display the form:
   $output = drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
  ```
- second method

  ```
   module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
   $node_type = 'YOURNODETYPE';
   $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
   global $user;
   $node = array(
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
  'type' => $node_type,
  );
  node_object_prepare($node);
  print drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
  ```
- third method

  ```
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $form = node_add('nodetype');
  $output = drupal_render($form);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using an old version of PHP. Have you tried also running "php -l your_file.php". That will run just the parser to see if you have any php syntax problem.