# How do I make a form in Add Content using Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

I am trying to get my Drupal 7 website working with PHP and an external database. I would like to have user interaction via forms, but all the examples I can find on the web hint that you have to write your own module to do this. I couldn't find a good description of even that process from the ground up. Is there a way to add a form using the standard Add Content -> Article or Basic Page? Is that a bad way to do things? I would like a page that is a form and when the user presses the submit button the same page loads, but now with the data retrieved from the database that was requested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you really can do this with it, but have a look on:
[Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you 3 method to  add a node programatically

- first method

  ```
  // required for Drupal 6
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
  // which nodeform you want
  $node_type = 'YOURNODETYPE';
  $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
  // maybe add current users info
  global $user;
  // create a blank node
  $node = array(
   'uid' => $user->uid,
   'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
   'type' => $node_type,
    );
    // Invoke hook_nodapi and hook_node
    node_object_prepare($node);
   // Or you can also use an exiting node, for example
   // $node = node_load(123);
   // and the display the form:
   $output = drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
  ```
- second method

  ```
   module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
   $node_type = 'YOURNODETYPE';
   $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
   global $user;
   $node = array(
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
  'type' => $node_type,
  );
  node_object_prepare($node);
  print drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
  ```
- third method

  ```
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $form = node_add('nodetype');
  $output = drupal_render($form);
  ```

[useful link(maybe)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11739/problem-using-module-load-include)

Comment: Where should I be putting the code examples you show? They look like the should go somewhere other than under the "add Content" Body section. Do I need to create a form API based function for that has $form_id for its name?

Comment: Also, all forms of your code throw lots of errors when I do enter them. Here are a few: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in node_object_prepare(), Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in node_object_prepare(), Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in node_type_get_base(), Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'Article_node_form' was given in drupal_retrieve_form()

Comment: Here's my code:`<?php // required for Drupal 6
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
// which nodeform you want
$node_type = 'Article';
$form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
// maybe add current users info
global $user;
// create a blank node
$node = array(
 'uid' => $user->uid,
 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
 'type' => $node_type,
  );
  // Invoke hook_nodapi and hook_node
  node_object_prepare($node);
 // Or you can also use an exiting node, for example
 // $node = node_load(123);
 // and the display the form:
 $output = drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
?>`

Answer (score -1):

no. I thought you want to do this in your custom module .
 if you not  very skillful in module developing  I suggest you use `php block`.
enable `PHP filter` module  in default core drupal module, then create a block  in `Home » Administration » Structure » Blocks` 
put this in `body`
**change nodetype to your optional contenttype you have**

```
  <?php
   module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
   $form = node_add('nodetype');
   $output = drupal_render($form);
   ?>
```

and in text filter select `php filter` .save it and in block list put it in your optional region and determine **Visibility settings** with you optional.

Comment: I think you assume that I know quite a bit more than I do, which is how I feel that all the help out there is. Do I really need to add a module if all I want to do is creating a form and some php interfacing? As far as nodetype goes, what should that be? Where do I specify the form action, the submit button, and other inputs for the form?